# Loss of precision while handling long arrays with very small numbers

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I am trying to process a calculation involving 3 very large arrays whose elements are very small values. When individual elements of the arrays are operated on, the outcome is as expected. But trying to process the entire arrays bring in a loss of precision of the output.

The following function is written as a part of a class that already contains the global variables (non-zero) named `particle_px`, `particle_py`, and `particle_pz`. They are all of the same length. `particle_px` and `particle_py` have similar elements, while `pz` is much smaller and its relevance can be ignored.

```
def calculate_particle_energy(self):
    """
    calculates the particle energes from the momenta in the current file. output in keV
    """
    print("particle_px is of " + str(type(self.particle_px)) + " with " + str(len(self.particle_px)) + " elements")
    print("particle_px[0] = " + str(self.particle_px[0]))
    a = (self.particle_px**2 + self.particle_py**2 + self.particle_pz**2) / (2 * self.particle_mass*1.6022*(10**-16))
    print("denominator = " + str(2 * self.particle_mass*1.6022*(10**-16)))
    print("numerator_single = " + str(self.particle_px[0]**2 + self.particle_py[0]**2 + self.particle_pz[0]**2))
    print("numerator_array = " + str((self.particle_px**2 + self.particle_py**2 + self.particle_pz**2)[0]))
    print("correct a0 = " + str((self.particle_px[0]**2 + self.particle_py[0]**2 + self.particle_pz[0]**2) / (2 * self.particle_mass*1.6022*(10**-16))))
    print("wrong a0 = " + str(a[0]))
```

The above snippet gives the following outcome:

```
particle_px is of <class 'numpy.ndarray'> with 48933106 elements
particle_px[0] = 1.1980471e-25
denominator = 2.9190097272000005e-46
numerator_single = 1.817622024655414e-50
numerator_array = 0.0
correct a0 = 6.226844699140246e-05
wrong a0 = nan
```

I was expecting same values for `numerator_single` and `numerator_array`. To gauge whether the issue is just with the visibility of the decimal points, I have calculated `a0`.

The correct output should have been something like this:

```
particle_px is of <class 'numpy.ndarray'> with 48933106 elements
particle_px[0] = 1.1980471e-25
denominator = 2.9190097272000005e-46
numerator_single = 1.817622024655414e-50
numerator_array = 1.817622024655414e-50
correct a0 = 6.226844699140246e-05
wrong a0 = 6.226844699140246e-05
```

The above is being run on a cluster with numpy 1.18.1. I tried to generate the issue on my PC(numpy 1.24.1) but could not reproduce it. an array of 3 elements on my PC is giving correct results.

```
import numpy as np

class particle_energy:

    def __init__(self):
        self.particle_px = np.array([2e-26,4e-26,5e-26])
        self.particle_py = np.array([2e-26,4e-26,5e-26])
        self.particle_pz = np.array([2e-26,4e-26,5e-26])
        self.particle_mass = 9.10938 * (10 ** -31)
        
    def calculate_particle_energy(self):
        """
        calculates the particle energes from the momenta in the current file. output in keV
        """
        print("particle_px is of " + str(type(self.particle_px)) + " with " + str(len(self.particle_px)) + " elements")
        print("particle_px[0] = " + str(self.particle_px[0]))
        a = (self.particle_px**2 + self.particle_py**2 + self.particle_pz**2) / (2 * self.particle_mass*1.6022*(10**-16))
        print("denominator = " + str(2 * self.particle_mass*1.6022*(10**-16)))
        print("numerator_single = " + str(self.particle_px[0]**2 + self.particle_py[0]**2 + self.particle_pz[0]**2))
        print("numerator_array = " + str((self.particle_px**2 + self.particle_py**2 + self.particle_pz**2)[0]))
        print("correct a0 = " + str((self.particle_px[0]**2 + self.particle_py[0]**2 + self.particle_pz[0]**2) / (2 * self.particle_mass*1.6022*(10**-16))))
        print("wrong a0 = " + str(a[0]))

def main():
    pen = particle_energy()
    pen.calculate_particle_energy()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The results (with the smaller arrays) are exactly as expected:

```
particle_px is of <class 'numpy.ndarray'> with 3 elements
particle_px[0] = 2e-26
denominator = 2.9190097272000005e-46
numerator_single = 1.2e-51
numerator_array = 1.2e-51
correct a0 = 4.1109832174183095e-06
wrong a0 = 4.1109832174183095e-06
```

I believe there is a loss in precision while handling the massive arrays.

1. Am I right about this assumption?
2. If yes, then how do I avoid this loss and calculate correct values?
3. What is the best way to perform this calculation (accuracy and speed)?

Comment: Post the version of `numpy` on both platforms you use? I don't know the answer to your question; maybe these details are relevant.

Comment: Please try removing details which are not relevant to your problem. For example, I think you can simplify your code by using `particle_px**2` instead of the more complicated calculation. Or maybe cut your array to a small size (e.g. 1 element) and using exactly the same data on both platforms — the problem is, in my opinion, in the difference in platforms and not in array size.

Comment: When run on the cluster, what is the data type of `self.particle_px`?  Try printing `self.particle_px.dtype`.  You might run into overflow or underflow issues if the arrays are `float32`.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with your example with length 3 arrays if I change the data type of `particle_px`, `particle_py` and `particle_pz` to `np.float32`.

Comment: The dtype of self.particle_px is indeed float32. Should it be typecast into a regular float(64) to avoid this error? why is the error occurring only in the array  ?

Comment: I converted the array to float64. The results are correct and as expected. Thank you. But I am still confused about why this loss in precision is happening only during the array operation and not when individual values are processed.

Comment: It is a quirk of numpy that the casting behaviors of scalars and arrays are different.  Array operations preserve the dtype, so if `x` is an array and has dtype `float32`, then `x**2` will also have dtype `float32`.  In your example, if `self.particle_px = np.array([2e-26, 4e-26, 5e-26], dtype=np.float32)`, then `self.particle_px**2` also has dtype `float32`, and the squared values underflow to 0.  *Scalar* `float32` instances will upcast to `float64` instances in many cases, e.g. `np.float32(2e-26)**2` gives the `float64` value `3.999999909812819e-52` instead of underflowing to 0.

Comment: Clarification of that scalar example: the expression `np.float32(2e-26)**2` mixes two types: a `np.float32` instance and a Python integer.  That case results in an upcast to `np.float64`.  The upcast does not occur when both operands are `np.float32`, e.g. `np.float32(2e-26)**np.float32(2)` and `np.float32(2e-26)*np.float32(2e-26)` both give a result that is `np.float32` (and the value is 0.0 because of underflow).

Comment: @Ratul Aside: Do you expect `1.6022*(10**-16)` to have _exactly_ the same value as `1.6022e-16`?

Answer (score 3):

the array elements have a dtype of float32. Thus squaring them results in an underflow and the values go to 0.
This does not happen for the individual values as numpy typecasts the values to float64.

Thus for the code to yield reliable results, arrays should be converted to float64 before squaring.

> ```
> self.particle_px = self.particle_px.astype(np.float64)
> ```

Thanks to Warren Weckesser for the answer

Comment: think this might also be a use of the [`float_power` method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.float_power.html).  e.g. compare results of `np.float_power(x, 2)` vs `np.power(x, 2)`